# How to fix error (Could not open for reading! File does not exist) when reading xlsx file with PHPExcel Api in Codeigniter from input file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm getting error 500 when i try to read xlsx file using PHPExcel Api.

When i read file from input:

`$objReader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`

=> it's not working. i get this error:
`Message: Could not open for reading! File does not exist.`

However when i log `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` i get the file path:
`C:\wamp64\tmp\xxxx.tmp`

and when i try another file like this:
`$objReader->load('c://test.xlsx);`
it works

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('excel');
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
print $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getValue();
```

Comment: Please add condition `if(file_exists($file_path)){}` and add your code between in.

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you have to `move_uploaded_file()` to an accessible location first? See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php